# Why shared_ptr doesn't call a destructor of a pointer when exception occured

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr

I tested C++11 shared_ptr, and was surprised
In this example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <exception>

using namespace std;

class MyExc
{

};

class Slot
{
public:
    Slot(const std::string &str = "NONAME") : m_name(str)
    {
        cout << "Constructor of slot: " << m_name << endl;
    }

    virtual ~Slot()
    {
        cout << "Destructor of slot: " << m_name << endl;
    }

    void sayName()
    {
        cout << "Slot name is: " << m_name << endl;
//       throw MyExc();
    }

private:
    string m_name;
};


void testShared(shared_ptr<Slot> & m_share)
{
    m_share->sayName();
}

int main()
{
    vector<shared_ptr<Slot>> vec {make_shared<Slot>("0"), make_shared<Slot>("1"), make_shared<Slot>("2"), make_shared<Slot>("3"), make_shared<Slot>("4")};
    for (auto& x:vec)
        testShared(x);


    return 0;
}
```

I see right output

Constructor of slot: 0
Constructor of slot: 1
Constructor of slot: 2
Constructor of slot: 3
Constructor of slot: 4
Slot name is: 0
Slot name is: 1
Slot name is: 2
Slot name is: 3
Slot name is: 4
Destructor of slot: 0
Destructor of slot: 1
Destructor of slot: 2
Destructor of slot: 3
Destructor of slot: 4

But if I uncomment line

```
throw MyExc();
```

output has changed, and destructor calling message didn't show

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'MyExc'
Constructor of slot: 0
Constructor of slot: 1
Constructor of slot: 2
Constructor of slot: 3
Constructor of slot: 4
Slot name is: 0

Does it mean that memory leak is placed here?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, yes there is a memory leak (not that it matters much, since the program will terminate immediately and the OS will reclaim the memory).

To unerstand this, you need to be aware that stack unwinding (that is, destroying local variables when going up the call stack) is only guaranteed by the standard *if the exception is caught.* If the exception is never caught and goes straight to `std::terminate`, whether or not unwinding happens is up to the compiler & standard library.

Quoting C++11:

15.2:

> 1 As control passes from a *throw-expression* to a handler, destructors are invoked for all automatic objects
>   constructed since the try block was entered. The automatic objects are destroyed in the reverse order of the
>   completion of their construction.
>
> 3 The process of calling destructors for automatic objects constructed on the path from a try block to a
>   *throw-expression* is called *“stack unwinding.”* ...

15.3:

> 9 If no matching handler is found, the function `std::terminate()` is called; whether or not the stack is
>   unwound before this call to `std::terminate()` is implementation-defined (15.5.1).

Comment: Thank you, if I modify code to this:  

for (auto& x:vec) {
        try {
            testShared(x);
        } catch ( MyExc & ex){

            exit;

        }

>all works fine, and output is:  

Constructor of slot: 0  
Constructor of slot: 1  
Constructor of slot: 2  
Constructor of slot: 3  
Constructor of slot: 4  
Slot name is: 0  
Slot name is: 1  
Slot name is: 2  
Slot name is: 3  
Slot name is: 4  
Destructor of slot: 0  
Destructor of slot: 1  
Destructor of slot: 2  
Destructor of slot: 3  
Destructor of slot: 4

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning is a reason why it works like this: commonly, if an exception is unhandled, the program (or actually the OS) optionally saves a crash dump allowing the developer to load that crash dump in a debugger and figure out what went wrong. It doesn't usually matter for the end user (the program crashed either way), and *not* unwinding the stack makes for much more developer-friendly debugging by pointing right to the location where the exception was thrown, with all local variables still intact.